# Why Is PostQuitMessage Necessary

Tags: windows, message-loop

Pretty simple question. I was just curious why I would use PostQuitMessage(0) to break out of my Message Loop, instead of just doing something like:

```
bool isRunning;

case WM_DESTROY:
{
    isRunning = false;
    break;
}
```

Honestly, I don't really see any harm in doing it this way, but maybe there is some minutia I am not quite seeing.

Comment: it is not necessary, just a way to let GetMessage() return FALSE.  Not so sure that adding your own global variable scores any elegance points.

Comment: A post on this from the horse's mouth [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453). It does more than just break out of `GetMessage()`.

Comment: link Paul Sanders posted seems nonfunctional, but I guess it corresponds to [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453) nowadays